# c++ How to avoid case/switch statement

Tags: c++

I have a time series array. On each time series element a number of conditions that may evaluate to  true or false. I want to evaluate how many times a particular combination has been true in the past. For example let’s assume I have the following conditions:

```
cond1 = ……. Evaluates to true or false
```

thru

```
cond30 = ……. Evaluates to true or false
```

on time series array element100 cond1 and cond7 are true, therefore I want to create new variable lets call it truecond and assign cond1 and cond7 to it.

```
truecond = cond1 AND cond7
```

so I can check to see how many time in past this combination has been true. I can write a case/switch statement for all possible combination, but that is very cumbersome. Is there a more efficient approach to this problem?
I need a starting point. Thanks

Comment: You could use a `std::map` and store each condition.

Comment: what are the conditions? are they attributes of the element? Show us some code

Comment: Gearhead, I'd like to suggest that you should probably re-consider how you've *(so far)* **phrased** this question. In what you've written now, you have basically *assumed* "a `condN` variable implementation of" an **underlying objective** that you, in the question as-written, really haven't specifically addressed. You also haven't offered us any *source code.* Please back-off *(so to speak)* from "your present assumptions of 'how to do it," and tell us more about "what, exactly, you are aiming to do." Very likely, a solution that **doesn't** involve `condN` variables is lurking here...

Comment: I didn't know where to start so I don't have any code yet. However conditions can be anything like cond1 = Temp > 30 cond2 = humidity <= 60 cond3 = pressure == 50

Comment: "Okay, we understand that 'you don't have any code yet,'" and I sense the point-of-view that you're now using to attempt to frame your problem: both the time-series elements `element`, and the conditions `cond`, are being expressed-by-you as *discrete variable-names,* `elementNNN` and `condNNN`,* when in all probability there are abundant reasons *not* to do so in the c++ language. *(Stats packages, on the other hand, might give you no choice.)* Believe me ... we understand ...!

Comment: Mike I didn't know how to phrase my question better. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to store data when the basic keys and values are computable (by looking it up in a data stream, say) is to store it as key value pairs in a dictionary.

Take a look at std::map.

Answer (score 0):

You can code this up as binary.  For each condition, give it a power of 2 so you have a unique number for every bool combo.  I.e.

```
truecond = cond1 AND cond7 => 2**0 + 2**6 = 65
```

combined with a map like HackSaw suggested, you then can have a map of all combos that you can increment for each step and thus see how many times a combination of conditions were flipped.

Comment: Thank you to all for your responses. This gives me a starting point.